# use dataframe groupby agg within a foor loop with predefiend functions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

how would like to execute the following for loop

```
operation = ['mean','std']
for i in range(0,len(operation)):
    df2 = df.groupby(level='Index').agg(operation[i]).dropna(how='all')
    ....
```

but using the function from numpy

```
operation = ['np.mean','np.std']
for i in range(0,len(operation)):
    df2 = df.groupby(level='Index').agg(operation[i]).dropna(how='all')
    ....
```

in particular I want to use `ddof=1`

could you please tell me how?

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: no but I would like to pass the parameter ddof=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the actual functions rather than the strings, i.e.:

```
operation = [np.mean, np.std]
```

To pass arguments to the functions, you can pass a `lambda` with the function arguments. For example:

```
operation = [np.mean, lambda x: np.std(x, ddof=1)]
```